# How to use qt libraries in ros

Tags: ros, library, qtcreator, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dear
I'm working with Ubuntu 12.10 and ros hydro
I want to use qt libraries in ros. So I try to use simple library like "QDebug"  and I write this program and Cmake

```
#include "QDebug"
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "Qt_test");
  qDebug()<<"Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

and cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
rosbuild_add_executable(first_test src/first_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

but when I try to make my package with rosmake this error occurd.

> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   mkdir -p bin   cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
> ..   [rosbuild] Building package
> qt_test   -- Using
> CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX:
> /home/hamid/working_space/qt_test/build/devel
> -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro   -- This workspace
> overlays: /opt/ros/hydro   -- Using
> Debian Python package layout   --
> Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON   --
> Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
> -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/hamid/working_space/qt_test/build/test_results
> -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
> -- catkin 0.5.77   [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/hydro/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/hydro/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/hydro/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34
> (target_link_libraries):
> Cannot specify link libraries for target "qt_test" which is not built by
> this project.
>
> ```
>  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> ```
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

Is there anyone help me?
I  know about cmake a little.Could anyone give me link for cmake that how to do this?
thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104666/how-to-use-qt-libraries-in-ros/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found my problem
rosbuild_add_executable(first_test src/first_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
Make both qt_test, or both first_test.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4